# C++, select function by template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, runtime

My question is how to call one of `process` function by runtime-known `id` without using map?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

enum id
{
    id_1,
    id_2,
    id_3
};

template <id id_>
void process();

template<>
void process<id_1>()
{
    std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void process<id_2>()
{
    std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void process<id_3>()
{
    std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
}

std::map<id, void(*)()> mapping =
{
    {id_1, process<id_1>},
    {id_2, process<id_2>},
    {id_3, process<id_3>}
};

int main()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        mapping[static_cast<id>(rand()%3)]();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need some sort of container and type erasure to do this. The map-based approach in your example is appropriate

Comment: What is wrong with using a map for this?

Comment: The provided solution looks ok to me. If you have room to put a bit more constraint, you can even go for an `array` or `vector` instead of  `map`

Comment: Is `unordered_map` ok? May be faster at times. [This is just a tongue in cheek comment. `map` like container is the best suited for your example/requirement.]

Comment: Thanks for comments, I was looking for solution without any "registration" of function in map but it seems there is no such solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`map` is an elegant solution.**

If you don't want to use `map`, you have to 'map' the function calls yourself.

> switch-case

```
void mapped_process(id id_) {
    switch (id_) {
    case id_1:
        process<id_1>();
        break;
    case id_2:
        process<id_2>();
        break;
    case id_3:
        process<id_3>();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

mapped_process(static_cast<id>(rand()%3);
```

> map by index

Just as one of the comment mentioned, you can use `array` or `vector` to replace `map` with some constraint: the enums have unique values.

```
std::array<void(*)(), 3> procs = {process<id_1>, process<id_2>, process<id_3>};

procs[rand() % 3]();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think map a better (less to code) than switch-case, although it slower.